# How does RBTree's color trick work?

Tags: c, red-black-tree

In wikipedia : [Red-black_tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)

> > Tracking the color of each node requires only 1 bit of information per node because there >are only two colors. The tree does not contain any other data specific to its being a red–>black tree so its memory footprint is almost identical to classic (uncolored) binary search >tree. In many cases the additional bit of information can be stored at no additional memory >cost.

And I found an implement of [rbtree](https://github.com/marmotw/libtree/blob/master/rb.c) in C:

```
#ifdef UINTPTR_MAX

static inline enum rb_color get_color(const struct rbtree_node *node)
{
    return node->parent & 1;
}

static inline void set_color(enum rb_color color, struct rbtree_node *node)
{
    node->parent = (node->parent & ~1UL) | color;
}

static inline struct rbtree_node *get_parent(const struct rbtree_node *node)
{ 
    return (struct rbtree_node *)(node->parent & ~1UL);
}

static inline void set_parent(struct rbtree_node *parent, struct rbtree_node *node)
{
    node->parent = (uintptr_t)parent | (node->parent & 1);
}

#else
...
#endif
```

My question is how this color trick works?Thx.

Comment: Are you asking about the [bit twiddling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using a(n incredibly sketchy) trick of altering the pointer to the parent to store a single bit, which indicates the color. The least significant bit in that pointer contains the color:

```
static inline enum rb_color get_color(const struct rbtree_node *node)
{
    return node->parent & 1;
}
```

If the low bit is `0` then the color is, say, red, and if the low bit is `1` then the color is black. (Realize that it's irrelevant whether red is `0` and black is `1`, or vice versa).

---

[@Daniel Fischer commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291007/how-does-rbtrees-color-trick-work/16291035?noredirect=1#comment23319556_16291035) with a link that warrants being brought out of the comments:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_tagging

...which is precisely the technique used here.

Comment: And the reason why this works is because pointers are required to be aligned right? So a pointer will never naturally have the 1 bit set?

Comment: I don't think you emphasized **INCREDIBLY SKETCHY** enough. Who writes code like this?!? And then publishes it... *GAG*.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis People who write C for fun

Comment: @Patashu yes and no. It's a horrible assumption to make. Consider this example: `struct rbtree_node *n = (struct rbtree_node *)(1 + (unsigned char *)malloc(1 + sizeof(struct rbtree_node)));`. FOr some weird reason I wanted to allocate an extra byte of memory and store it alongside the pointer. Perfectly valid thing to do. Except now your red-black tree is **totally borked**.

Comment: @Patashu **NO**, please who are *IDIOTS* write code like that.

Comment: @NikBougalis "Perfectly valid thing to do" may be wrong. There may be alignment requirements for a `struct rbtree_node`. Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_tagging

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the link - definitely relevant.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess I can grudgingly agree with that, even if I think it's horrible. But, ultimatey, it doesn't make the code posted by the OP any better or less of a horror show.

Comment: @NikBougalis It's not portable, sure. It allows the user to horribly break it if (s)he wants. But is it really **so** horrible? (What's the alternative?)

Comment: @DanielFischer Tagged pointers (wasn't familiar with the name) are fine and dandy. Hell, Windows uses this techique to stuff some extra information in the lower bits of handles and in page table entries.  But my point, which I stand by, is that it's a silly technique 99.9% of the time and, more than than, it's almost certainly a *bad* idea, especially when you don't have complete control over the values you're "tagging". And all for what? The savings almost certainly fall within the "noise" of memory operations, and are unlikely to matter on all but the most memory-constrained systems.

Comment: @NikBougalis I question your percentage, but I agree with the tendency. I just seem to feel less strongly about it.

Comment: I tend to use "99.9%" as "indeterminate but almost certainly very very large". Your point is well-taken. I don't have specific statistics.

Comment: Thanks all,I got this, and I saw the definition of $struct rbtree_node has $__attribute__((aligned(2))) .This promises the alignment,and so this trick works.

Comment: I think this trick has its space，and that's a deal.Although now It's so obscure.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Noise of the system? I believe you're thinking small. Using a separate value will be another 4 bytes because of alignment. Over several hundred thousand nodes this adds up. It also causes cache problems because of the wasted space. I saw some Linux Gnome code go from using 5 MB to 120 MB because it was ported to the "generic" data structures in glib. Added 5 pointers to each node, at 8 bytes each when the data itself was rarely more than 8 bytes. What a waste of space. But oh so "generic" and easy to program. I guess.

Comment: @ZanLynx sarcasm aside, you'll always be able to find corner cases - software design is all about make decisions because one size doesn't fit all. I still stand by what I said: "tagged pointers" are almost always *not* a good idea and almost always *not* worth the savings and *usually* a bad omen. Your example (vague as it is) proves only that developers need to analyze the cost along with the benefits when they choose a particular approach and/or solution. Were other "generic" glib data structures available that were better suited? Who knows? You don't even tell us what was used...

Comment: @NikBougalis: I don't recall the application. It was 2007 and I was using Gentoo Linux on 64-bit and I noticed a new version of the app was using huge piles of RAM. It went from a custom tree to using GObject and GTree. Instead of embedding key data directly in the tree it was a pointer. The value became a GObject with extra info such as a type pointer and reference count, and GTree uses a separate integer field for coloring information. It was not so bad in a 32-bit environment but in 64-bit? 5 to 120 is two orders of magnitude. TL;DR: Using more space because you can is a slippery slope.